# Adding a do/while loop

Tags: c++, do-while

I need to add a do/while loop to this code using another != N || another != n. Trouble is I am absolutely horrid with do/while loops and am not quite sure where I should place everything. Would it be before the switch itself? Or before the entire input module?

```
//Compiler Directives

#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

//Constant Declarations

const int LOWERBOUND = 400;
const int UPPERBOUND = 2400;

//Main Body

int main(){
    //Local Identifiers

    int year, leapCode;

    //Input Module 

    cout<<"Please enter a year in the range 400 to 2400\t";
    cin>>year;

    //Process Module

    if ((year >= LOWERBOUND)&& (year <= UPPERBOUND)){
        if (year%4!=0)
           leapCode = 1;
        else
           if (year%100!=0)
              leapCode = 2;
        else
          if (year%400!=0)
              leapCode = 3;
        else
              leapCode = 4;
        switch(leapCode){
              case 1:
                cout<<"The year "<<year<<" is not a leap year\n";
                break;
             case 2:
                cout<<"The year "<<year<<" is a leap year\n";
                break;
             case 3:
                cout<<"The year "<<year<<" is a century year but not a leap year\n";
                break;
             case 4:
                cout<<"The year "<<year<<" is a leap century year";
                break;  
        } //end switch
    }
    else
    cout<<"The year is out of range\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: at least try something

Comment: People on SO usually won't do your homework.

Comment: Ask yourself what you NEED to do absolutely once, then maybe many times. That should give you an hint.

Comment: try doing a `while(true)` and add a `break` on the exit condition - i find that easier to read

Comment: another hint, want do you want to happen many times. Do you want to ask the user to enter a number many times?  or just process the same number many times ? Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Do/While loops are used whenever you need to loop a code block from 0 to N number of times, meaning that you need to run a given code block at least once until the exit condition gets satisfied.

In your case you'd have to place the `do`/`while` loop just before your `leap` and `year` variables declaration and close it right after your `system("PAUSE")` line, basically most of your `main()` method. Once you have determine the result of the processing within your switch block, update your "another" variable (or whatever other variable you'd like to use in your `do`/`while` condition).

By doing this your program will go into the `do`/`while` loop for the first time and print your output String, then will do your processing with the user input, once it reaches the end of the loop, it will evaluate the loop condition inside the `while` clause to determine if the code block should executed again, if so, your program will ask for another input to the user and then it will process it.

```
//Compiler Directives

#include < iostream >
#include < cstdlib >

using namespace std;

//Constant Declarations

const int LOWERBOUND = 400;
const int UPPERBOUND = 2400;

//Main Body

int main()
{
    //Local Identifiers

    do {
        int year, leapCode;
        //declare "another" variable

        //Input Module 
        cout << "Please enter a year in the range 400 to 2400\t";
        cin >> year;

        //Process Module
        if ((year >= LOWERBOUND) && (year <= UPPERBOUND)) {
            if (year % 4 != 0)
                leapCode = 1;
            else
                if (year % 100 != 0)
                    leapCode = 2;
                else
                    if (year % 400 != 0)
                        leapCode = 3;
                    else
                        leapCode = 4;
            switch (leapCode) {
                case 1:
                    cout << "The year " << year << " is not a leap year\n";
                    //update "another" variable
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "The year " << year << " is a leap year\n";
                    //update "another" variable
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cout << "The year " << year << " is a century year but not a leap year\n";
                    //update "another" variable
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cout << "The year " << year << " is a leap century year";
                    //update "another" variable
                    break;
            } //end switch
        }
        else
            cout << "The year is out of range\n";
            //update "another" variable

        system("PAUSE");
    } while (another != "N" || another != "n");

    return 0;
}
```